# Woocommerce version issue in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My current site is in wordpress version 3.0.3.It works fine now.Now i want to add plugin of woocommerce for ecommerce.Problem is that there isn't any woocommerce version that is suitable in wordoress-3.0.3. I don't want to update wordpress version.Now how can i add this plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WooCommerce as of v2.1 requires WordPress 3.8. That being said you could get an older version from the [Github](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce) repository that is still compatible with your WordPress version, but I don't think that's a good idea. Upgrading WordPress to the latest version should be your topmost priority.

If you still want to do it, go to Github and switch to tag v2.0.20, thin click the Download ZIP button on the right. Or use git clone on the command line if you're familiar with this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try downloading [this](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/releases/tag/v1.6.0) (earliest possible) version, it is 1.6.

However, I *highly* recommend to upgrade your `Wordpress` to at least version 3.4 (you maybe do not want to proceed, but it is important, because older versions contain many security issues, so if you plan to use e-commerce on your blog - it is madness to do it with such old versions of `Woocommerce` and `Wordperss`).

Comment: Thanks for you reply.I already tried woocommerce's oldest version but it wouldn't work for me.If i will update the wordpress version then my site will be mashup.I need to change some plugin also as per current version.